# @Elementcollection with query be example don't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have this entity class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "object_id", nullable = false)
    private String objectId;
    @Column(name = "car_year")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.SMALLINT)
    private Year year;
    @OneToOne
    private Model model;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "cars_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "category")
    private Set<Category> categories;
// constructor
```

Here i use @ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class). Because my Category is enam:

```java
@Getter
public enum Category {
    SUV("SUV"),
    SEDAN("Sedan"),
    COUPE("Coupe"),
    CONVERTIBLE("Convertible"),
    PICKUP("Pickup"),
    VAN("Van/Minivan"),
    SPORT("Sport"),
    HATCHBACK("Hatchback"),
    WAGON("Wagon"),
    CROSSOVER("Crossover"),
    ;
    private final String name;

    Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Category> LABEL_TO_CATEGORY = Arrays.stream(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Category::getName, Function.identity()));

    public static Category valueOfLabel(String label){
        return LABEL_TO_CATEGORY.get(label.trim());
    }
}
```

So, how you can see in db i use "link table (sorry if wrong naming idr how it's call)"

```sql
CREATE TABLE cars_categories
(
    car_id   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR(255)
);

ALTER TABLE cars_categories
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_car_categories_on_car FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES cars (object_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Well, now about problem. I have this method in my service:

```java
public List<CarDto> getCarByExample(CarDto carDto) {
        Example<Car> example = Example.of(carMapper.carDtoToCar(carDto));
        
        return repository.findAll(example).stream()
                .map(carMapper::carToCarDto).toList();
    }
```

What do I expect if my car obj have only Set<Category> findAll() with example get all cars with same Category.

But now findAll(example) return all cars from db. And i second day can't understand why hibernate create basic query findAll()

`Hibernate: select c1_0.object_id,c1_0.model_model_id,c1_0.car_year from cars c1_0`

update: I also forgot to say, I tried all fetch types. Query doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find mistake (omg it's so simple). Query by Example can't work with Collections.

[Here is the link to the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871967/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example-with-access-to-nested-objects-attributes/53364539#53364539)

For fix my issue i must use Querydsl
[Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Comment: that's why I suggested you use `fetch join` by JPQL query

Comment: Yeah it's make sense. But QBE just can't use Collections in query.

Answer (score 0):

`ElementCollection` is LAZY by default, change to `@ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Or you can rewrite the query with a `fetch join` statement

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I tried changing fetch type, it didn't help.

Comment: Hmm.. your mapped join_column are different.. tried with referencedColumnName?

Comment: ``` java
// I just tried it. Behavior hasn't changed at all:(
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "cars_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "object_id"))
```

Comment: sorry idk why code formatting doesn't work

Comment: Hmm jpa logged only this query? Nothing more like "subquery"? Did you tried this `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` ?

Comment: I think so, but now I'll try again

Comment: Yeah, i try all fetches still same query
Hibernate: select c1_0.object_id,c1_0.model_model_id,c1_0.car_year from cars c1_0